# C# Non-String Localization

Tags: c#, localization

How would you localize things that are not strings.  For example, coins with values.

in the US, there are 5 basic coins:

```
Dollar: 1.00
Quarter :.25
Dime: .10
Nickel: .05
Penny: .01
```

But in Canada there 7:

```
Toonie: 2.00
Loonie: 1.00
Half Dollar: .50
Dollar: 1.00
Quarter :.25
Dime: .10
Nickel: .05
Penny: .01
```

What is the best way to L10n something like this?

Comment: Resource files may contain other objects than strings.

Comment: They speak "en-CA" in Canada, eh.  And "fr-CA", oui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, l10n and i18n always has to cover more than just strings, e.g. icons and images may just as well be locale-dependent. So you could put arbitrary non-string data into a resource.

In your specific case I'd just put the list into a string and localize that:

```
en-US 1,Dollar;.25,Quarter;.1,Dime;.05,Nickel;.01,Penny
en-CA 2,Toonie;1,Loonie;1,Dollar;.5,Half Dollar;...
```

And then parse that string and build your list of coin denominations. Your code apparently already is able to handle arbitrary such lists.

Comment: Would something like serializing the objects as json be acceptable? or would it be considered "too heavy"?

Comment: It's totally fine. It doesn't really matter what exactly the resource stores, but more how you process it. It would be inefficient to deserialize/parse the resource string everytime you encounter a coin value. The method of choice should be to only deserialize/parse it once and then cache it. As you would need to have a service method handling such a "complex" resource anyway (i.e. here a service method that takes a coin value and returns the localized coin text), this can be done transparently.